# Setting up socket.io server on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I've got a problem to run the server with socketIO module on AWS EC2 server.

[error1 screenshot](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/21/3e69b5dc4ed67dadabc774f4bd9e8232-full.png)

I have tried to edit inbound rule but it did not work

[error2 screenshot](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/21/22edbf8e6636305c03cd588805b25521-full.png)

Code works perfect on localhost but when I try it on aws ec2 , it is not working.

- Frontend port : 80
- backend socket.io server : 8081
- tcp socket server: 8124

**FRONTEND CODE**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

class Nokta extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          res_enlem: 41.018350,
          endpoint: "http://172.31.36.93:8081",
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {endpoint} = this.state;
        //Very simply connect to the socket
        const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
        socket.on("giden enlem", data => {
          this.setState({res_enlem: data.enlem});
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <Marker
          latitude={this.state.res_enlem}
          longitude={this.state.res_boylam}>
          </Marker>
        )
    }
}

export default Nokta;
```

website = [website link](http://enisyildiz.xyz/)

Comment: Looks like you are using localhost (127.0.0.1) as your host, use your `IPv4 Public IP` in your `EC2` instance instead

Comment: Please share the frontend WebSocket connection code also

Comment: from whatever connection code you have shared, it shouldn't connect to localhost

Comment: @AsnimPAnsari I edited the question

Comment: @DilanTharaka I changed it but it didn't work but now error is : net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Problem solved guys.Thanks for everything.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer? @EnisYıldız